# How to update the keystore property at runtime with a newly uploaded keystore file?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keystore, truststore

I'm accessing a https URL with certificate added to my application keystore property.

However, there is a recent change in the certificate of the target https URL.

We don't want to recompile the code and rebuild the ear file again with the updated keystore manually but would like to upload it to a location programmatically and want to refer the updated keystore in the application.

When we do that the second time setProperty() on updated keystore is not working [when we upload the new keystore file].

Please help us resolving the issue.

Thanks,
Jaya Krishna

Comment: How is deploying new code to solve this problem better than deploying new data?

Answer (score 0):

The `javax.net.ssl.*` system properties will only be loaded once.

You'll need to create your own [`X509KeyManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509KeyManager.html) to load the key/cert from the keystore more dynamically and make your application use an `SSLContext` initialised with it.

Comment: Thanks Bruno! Could you please elaborate more or provide any reference links or pointers here?